# Check if list contains a text

Tags: android, listview

I have a list and a custom adapter:

```
ItemModelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ItemModelList);
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

I also have an EditText where I add items to list, and an imageView as button to add:

```
 addLesson = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addLesson);
 AddLesson = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewAdd);
```

When i press the add button, i want to check if the text inside the editext already exists in the listview. If exists i want to show a message, otherwise i want to add it in the list with a method(LessonRegistration).

```
AddLesson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Checking whether EditText is Empty or Not
            CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

            if(CheckEditText){


                // If EditText is not empty then this block will execute.
                if (ItemModelList.contains(LessonNameHolder)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else {
                    LessonRegistration(LessonNameHolder, CodeItem);
                    }


            }
            else {

                // If EditText is empty then this block will execute .
                Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Add Lesson", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

LessonNameHolder has the String value of text from the editext.
My problem is that the button adds items to the listView even if they are already there. I think the problem is here: 
`if (ItemModelList.contains(LessonNameHolder))`...

Maybe something with the objects in the ItemModelList.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemModelList` is a list of `Model` objects. `LessonNameHolder` is a `String`. That means that, no matter what items are in `ItemModelList`, the `contains()` call will always return `false` (since no `String` is a `Model`).

You will have to write your own "contains" method that does the checking in a custom manner. Let's assume that each `Model` instance has a field called `lessonName`. Then you could write something like this:

```
public static boolean contains(List<Model> list, String lessonName) {
    for (Model model : list) {
        if (model.getLessonName().equals(lessonName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can replace this line:

> ```
> if (ItemModelList.contains(LessonNameHolder)){
> ```

with this:

```
if (contains(ItemModelList, LessonNameHolder)){
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I knew that something was wrong with the string value of LessonNameHolder and the items from the list. It works like a charm now. Thank you again!